# ofstream writes hex instead of char*

Tags: c++, file, ofstream

I try to write a simple Logger but the ofstream writes hex instead of the characters to the file.
Definition:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#define LOG Logger::getInstance()
class Logger
{
public:
    static Logger m_instance;
    static Logger &getInstance()
    {
        if (m_logfile == nullptr)
        {
            m_logfile = new std::ofstream(m_logfile_string.c_str(),
                                          std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
        }
        return m_instance;
    }

    Logger &operator<<(const std::string &c);
    Logger &operator<<(const char c[]);

private:
    static std::ofstream *m_logfile;
    static std::string m_logfile_string;
    Logger() {};
    Logger(const Logger &) = delete;
    Logger(Logger &&other) = delete;
    Logger &operator=(const Logger &other) = delete;
    Logger &operator=(Logger &&other) = delete;

    ~Logger()
    {
        if (m_logfile != nullptr)
            m_logfile->close();
    };

    std::string currentDateTime() const;
};
```

Impl.

```
#include "Logger.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

Logger Logger::m_instance;
std::ofstream *Logger::m_logfile = nullptr;
std::string Logger::m_logfile_string = "log.txt";

Logger &Logger::operator<<(const std::string &c)
{
    this->operator<<(c.c_str());
    return *this;
}

Logger &Logger::operator<<(const char c[])
{
    std::cout << currentDateTime() << " - "
              << c << std::endl;
    m_logfile->operator<<(c);
    return *this;
}

// Get current date/time, format is YYYY-MM-DD.HH:mm:ss
std::string Logger::currentDateTime() const
{
    auto now = time(nullptr);
    struct tm  tstruct;
    char       buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d.%X", &tstruct);

    return buf;
}
```

Usage:

```
#include "Logger.h"
void main()
{
    LOG << "started"; // Logger::getInstance() << "started";
}
```

Outcome:
`00007FF696EF3C00` in the `log.txt` The console output is right.

Whats going wrong here?

Comment: Did you try `Logger &Logger::operator<<(const char* c)` already?

Comment: Yes same result if i change the method to `const char*`

Comment: It's printing the pointer instead of the contents of the string. Which toolchain and OS are you using? Seems to work ok on Mac OS X with clang and gcc.

Comment: Working with VS13 v120 on Windows 8.1

Comment: Post a complete minimal testcase that we can dump into a compiler. None of this "..." nonsense and you don't precisely state the inputs and outputs.

Comment: It doesn't work on Mac either - was looking at the console output, not the file output.

Comment: Updated as whished. Containing all includes. Yes right the console output is working right but the file ouput does not work right.

Comment: Sigh can't you put it in a single file? You're making us work!

Comment: BTW `main` returns `int`, not `void`. Always.

Comment: [sigh] if I call my garage and tell them 'my car is not working right', they won't tell me how to fix it.  Go figure..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use member function of `iostream`:

```
m_logfile->operator<<(c);
```

There is no member function `operator<<(char* c)`, but there is `operator<<(void* p)`, so pointer is implicitly converted. See documentation on [`ostream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/).

Operators for `char*` are not class member functions:

```
 ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const char* s);
```

See here: [operator<< (ostream)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/)

So you need this code:

```
operator<<(*m_logfile, c);
```

Or much more cleaner:

```
(*m_logfile) << c;
```

---

Test example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout.operator<<("test");
    operator<<(std::cout, "test");
    std::cout << "test";
}
```

Prints `0x400944testtest`.

Comment: okay this definite clears it. Didn't think about the implicit convention that this happens here.  Thanks for clerifying.

Answer (score 2):

If you use

```
(*m_logfile)<<c;
```

instead of

```
m_logfile->operator<<(c);
```

It will work.

**Reason:**

- Your syntax calls the member function [`ostream::operator<<()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) which is not defined for `char*` nor for `string`.  It's only defined for `void*` which always displays address in hex.
- The classic syntax calls here the non member function ostream [`std::operator<<(...)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3C%3C/) which has overloads for `string` and [`char*`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/)